# jQuery validation for file and text area

Tags: jquery, validation

I am currently trying to use jQuery to validate either a textarea or a file uploaded by a user. The only time it should not allow someone to go onto the next page is when both textarea and the file uploaded isValid is false.

This is the code I have

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$('#nomination-submit').click(function (e) {
    var fileValid = false;
    var textValid = true;
    $('textarea').each(function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
            textValid = false;
            //binds to onchange event of your input field
            $('file').bind('change', function () {
                var ext = $('#file').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
                if ($.inArray(ext, ['pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'rtf', 'txt']) == -1)
                { $('#fileExtension').slideDown("slow"); $('#fileSize').slideUp("slow"); fileValid = true; } else {
                    var filesize = (this.files[0].size);
                    if (filesize > 4194304)
                    { $('#fileSize').slideDown("slow"); fileValid = false; } else { fileValid = true; $('#fileSize').slideUp("slow"); }
                    $('#fileExtension').slideUp("slow"); $('#textOrFile').slideUp("slow");
                }
            })
        }
    })
    if (fileValid == false && textValid == false) {
        e.preventDefault();
        { $('#textOrFile').slideDown("slow"); }
    }
}) });
```

When I have it like this it will allow the user to go to the next page even if the input is invalid. For some reason when I do this or a nested if function it does not make sure both are not false which is the only time I want the user to go to the next page.

Comment: Just an observation but you don't bind your change event until they try to submit.  That is perhaps better separated from the submit event?  Also `$('input[type="file"]').on('change',` not `$('file')` might be more effective.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Originally these were two separate pieces of validation code. I needed to merge the two pieces of code and this was the way it made sense in my head. Otherwise I would have put it before the submit button but that didn't seem like the right place to place it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create some separation of your validation from animation.

Assume this markup:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit me" id="nomination-submit" />
<input type="file" id="fileMe" />
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
```

This code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var validMinSize = 4194304;
  var validTypes = ['pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'rtf', 'txt'];

  $('#nomination-submit').on('click submit', function(e) {
    var fileValid = false;
    var textValid = false;
    var fileInput = $('#fileMe')[0];

    textValid =  $('textarea').filter(function() {
       return ($.trim($(this).val()) !== '');
    }).length == $('textarea').length;

    var fileTypeValid = checkFileType(fileInput);
    fileValid = fileTypeValid ? true : checkFileSize(fileInput);
    var allInvalid = (!fileValid && !textValid);
    if (allInvalid) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#textOrFile').slideDown("slow");
    }
    console.log("Check:" + fileTypeValid + ":" + fileValid + ":" + textValid + ":" + allInvalid);
  });

  $('#fileMe').on('change', function() {
    var fileInput = this;
    if (checkFileType(fileInput)) {
      $('#fileExtension').slideDown("slow");
      $('#fileSize').slideUp("slow");
    } else {
      if (checkFileSize(fileInput)) {
        $('#fileSize').slideDown("slow");
      } else {
        $('#fileSize').slideUp("slow");
      }
      $('#fileExtension').slideUp("slow");
      $('#textOrFile').slideUp("slow");
    }
  });

  function checkFileType(fileInput) {
    var fileValid = false;
    var ext = fileInput.value.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if (!(validTypes.indexOf(ext) === -1)) {
      fileValid = true;
    }
    return fileValid;
  }

  function checkFileSize(fileInput) {
    var fileValid = false;
    fileValid = !!fileInput && !!fileInput.files[0] && !(fileInput.files[0].size <= validMinSize);
    return fileValid;
  }
});
```

Fiddle with the revised code: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/71Lufcf2/2/

Comment: There are multiple text boxes to validate. Sorry I should have clarified this before. I need it to validate either the 4 text areas or upload a file.

Comment: This is also still running into the same issue I had before. The validation doesn't get past validating the text boxes so it won't allow me to move on the page if I upload a file.

Comment: Easy to fix: reversed the check set to `var textValid = false;` then if any text area is filled, make it true.  If you need ALL textarea to be filled that is a slight change but this should get you started.

Comment: Note this is missing the animation objects but the post lacks any markup so I simply left it as is.

Comment: ALL textareas need to be filled out OR a file needs to be uploaded in order for them to move onto the next page.

Comment: Also I went onto Fiddle to use the code and for some reason the checkFileType does not display a message or recognize correct file types. I tried to put in a pdf which should be an accepted file type and it said the file type was invalid.

Comment: Yep, I had done a quick fix on some code and left a parenthesis pair out on the conditional.  I fixed that in the code and in the fiddle,.  You can change the file validation portion as needed, I simply filtered by the text not being empty as valid, then compared the length of those.